# Redirect to another page from CategoryController/View Action (Extended) takes long time?

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, controllers, redirect

I'm writing a dynamic redirect code that is when the url contains the parameter p (i.e. p=1),

`Ex: http://www.example.com/category?p=1`

Redirects to the below,

`Ex: http://www.example.com/category`

I have my code in the Category Controller (Extended)'s view action,

The code I have is that as follows,

```
include_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php';
class MT_Filter_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Catalog_CategoryController{

  public function viewAction(){

  $category = $this->_initCatagory();
  $CategoryUrlKey = $category->getUrl();        
  $PageNum = $this->getRequest()->getParam('p');

    if($PageNum==1){

        $this->_redirectUrl($CategoryUrlKey);

    }
    //Other Codes Here

  }
}
```

1. What am I missing?
2. Why It takes long time?

Comment: use exit(); after $this->_redirectUrl();

Answer (score 2):

**Change to include to require once**

`include_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php';`

to

`require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Catalog').DS.'CategoryController.php';`

**For redirection,it will better idea to use frontent controller redirection process**

```
  Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($category->getUrl($category))
                ->sendResponse();
exit();
```

### Alternative

In order to full fill your requirement, can  to use **Event/Observer**

Create a custom module and  using `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event for redirect to account page

**update:**

---

**Observer code:**

> ```
> <?php 
> class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
>
> public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
> {
>     $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
>     $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
>     $controller_action= $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
>
>        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
>
>
>   /* here check page no and redirect to specific field */
>     $this->getRequest()->getParam('p')   
>   if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p')==1):
>    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($category->getUrl($category));
> ```
>
> Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
>         exit();
>         endif;
>             return;
>         }
>
> ```
> }
> ```

**config.xml:**

> ```
> ....
> <config>
>  <global>
>    <config>
>      <events>
>       <catalog_controller_category_init_after>
>         <observers>
>             <redirect_to_account>
>             <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer/class>
>             <method>redirectNotLogged</method>
>             </redirect_to_account>
>         </observers>
>       </catalog_controller_category_init_after>
>     </events>
> </global>     
> </config>
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the observer `$category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();`
I want category url key. How to get that?

Comment: $category->getUrlKey(); try this..